# Problems with INetFwMgr on Windows Server 2012

Tags: .net, com, com-interop, windows-firewall, windows-server-2012

Using the following code works on every OS I've tested except for my Windows Server 2012 machine:

```
public static Type FwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr");

public static void Main()
{
  var fwMgr = (INetFwMgr) Activator.CreateInstance(FwMgrType);

  var ssh = fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts.Item(22, 
      NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP); // throws FileNotFoundException

  ssh.RemoteAddresses = "123.234.123.235";
}
```

The line that creates the `ssh` variable is throwing:

> The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

I don't understand what file it's not able to find. FirewallAPI.dll exists on the machine. I even built the interop assembly on the server using tlbimp.exe.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was that the firewall rule I was targeting couldn't be found. The particular rule that I was after was created by the server I am using. When I deleted that rule and recreated manually, things started working.

The FileNotFoundException had me believing that there was something missing in the guts of the operating system.